# VBA- Reset header for each section in word document

Tags: vba, excel, header

We have trouble when create word by VBA macro.

In my document, we has many sections and we need to reset header for each section.
In section 1, we add image 1. 
In section 2, we add image 2.

But currently, both image 1 & image 2 is added to section 1 while in section 2 we set: LinkToPrevious = False

What should we do or any solution for this issues?
Thank you,

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question to replicate your issue so that others can understand & help you better

Comment: I was just working on a similar sounding problem. I probably have a solution, but I'd like to see what you did before I use my time to write it down. Make sure to mention me in a comment so I am notified.

Comment: Dear Daniel, here my src:

Answer (score 0):

here my src:    p_appWord.Selection.Sections(p_appWord.Selection.Sections.count).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    p_appWord.Selection.Sections(p_appWord.Selection.Sections.count).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete

```
sh003_Logo.Shapes("LOGO_ENG").Copy
Set hdr = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
hdr.Range.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdFloatOverText, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
hdr.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
hdr.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
hdr.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 18
hdr.Range.InsertAfter "P-PageNumber" & vbLf & p_docNo
hdr.Range.Fields.Add Range:=hdr.Range.Words(3), Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
hdr.Range.Words(5).Font.Bold = True
hdr.Range.Words(5).Font.Size = 18
```